# How can I render an image in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a sample I'm building, that's using the Northwind database.
I have a view in which I show all the products for a specifc category and use a ul to generate items with an image and the products name and price.

I have used the code here, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/11/13/extending-mvc-returning-an-image-from-a-controller-action.aspx .

And have gotten to the point that if I right-click an image on my page I get
the follow for the image url.

This is the action method I provided, which just takes the Categores ID.
/image/show/1

My action method in my ImageController is as follows:

```
    //
    // GET: /Image/Show
    public ActionResult Show(int id)
    {
        var category = northwind.AllCategories().Single(c => c.CategoryID == id);
        byte[] imageByte = category.Picture;
        string contentType = "image/jpeg";

        return this.Image(imageByte, contentType);
    }
```

Note: Picture is a byte[]

I then call it in my view like this. (product is the Model for my view)

But I still can't get the image to be displayed.

Comment: Is the image displayed correctly when you navigate to the action's URL (/image/show/1)? If so, there is an error in the way you embed the image in your HTML.
Otherwise, inspect the data returned by your method using Fiddler2 or similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change action

```
public FileContentResult Show(int id)
{
    var category = northwind.AllCategories().Single(c => c.CategoryID == id);
    byte[] imageByte = category.Picture;
    string contentType = "image/jpeg";

    return File(imageByte, contentType);
}
```

and send a product instance to view and try this in View

```
<img src="<%: Url.Action("Show","Image",new { id = Model.Category.CategoryID  }) %>" />
```

Comment: You got it. Thanks for the help, just realized you had exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this method instead:

```
public FileContentResult Show(int id)
{
  var category = northwind.AllCategories().Single(c => c.CategoryID == id);  
  byte[] imageByte = category.Picture;  
  string contentType = "image/jpeg";
  return File(imageByte, contentType);
}
```

This should be basic approach if you don't use that extension. If this works the error is in extension if this doesn't work the error is somewhere else - probably in routing. Also check Gustav's answer!

Comment: I changed the method, but still no image is displayed. The url for the image show's to be /Image/Show?CategoryID=1 
and my route for the page is /Products/Browse/Beverages for example

Comment: Turns out I had to use an anoynomus type   <img src='<%= Url.Action( "Show", "Image", new {id = product.Category.CategoryID } ) %>' so that the route was /Image/Show/1, instead of /Image/Show?CategoryID=1. That and of course need to update the images in Northwind from bitmap to Jpeg.

Thanks for the help. :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is the problem you have, but I always capitalize the action and controller names:

```
<%= Url.Action( "Show", "Image", new { id = product.Category.CategoryID } ) %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to use an anoynomus type 
' so that the route was /Image/Show/1, instead of /Image/Show?CategoryID=1. That and of course needed to update the images in Northwind from bitmap to Jpeg.